# .gitignore not working for me; trying to ignore all .csv files in all directories

Tags: git

I've read lots of posts already, and I've tried what I've found (ie creating my `.gitignore` file with the SINGLE LINE `*.csv` within the root directory (ie the same directory containing the `.git` folder (that's the root directory, right?), then running `git rm -r --cached .` followed by `git add .` followed by `git commit -m "so tired of trying to ignore all csv files"` followed by `git push origin master`.  And yet, I still get many errors, all looking like:

```
remote: error: File zz_prep_stuff/z_csv_table_data/blah.csv is 485.89 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

So, clearly, something is wrong!  Again, my `.gitignore` file contains only the following code:

```
*.csv
```

Please advise!  Where am I going wrong?  How do I ignore ALL csv files in my project?  Thank you

Comment: Uh, what if you do `git commit -a` instead of just `git commit` ?

Comment: ```git commit -a``` ```On branch master``` ```nothing to commit, working tree clean```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/86072

Answer (score 2):

> And yet, I still get many errors,

But... if `blah.csv` has been committed to your repository in the past, it would *still* tracked by Git even if you add it to the `.gitignore` file.
The `.gitignore` file only ignores untracked files and does not ignore files that have already been committed to the repository.

You should use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)) in order to purge those `.csv` files from your past history (note: backup your repository first):

```
git filter-repo --path-glob '*.csv' --invert-paths
git push origin --force --all
```

It is using a [Filtering based on paths](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_filtering_based_on_paths_see_also_filename_callback).