# Have never pushed, but have committed. Want to stop tracking all files with given extension and never push those

Tags: git, github

Sorry for duplicating endlessly, but nothing has worked so far in the many posts I've read and in previous answers.  I have been working on a project in a local repo, and, when I made my initial commits, they included a bunch of csv files that I don't want pushed to Github.  After many commits, I added a `.gitignore` file with the single line `*.csv` which I understand will prevent future monitoring csv files in any directory of the project.  I also understand that a `.gitignore` file won't stop git from pushing files in the commit history, even though I've asked for them to be "ignored."

Furthermore, I have tried cloning the project, but this doesn't seem to address anything.  I think that this also clones the commit history, so nothing is achieved regarding a "clean history" that doesn't include the files I want ignored.  Same errors when I try to push.  After cloning, I also tried `git filter-repo --path *.csv --force` per some answers here, but this seemed to just delete everything in the cloned repo yikes!  I've also tried the things always suggested, ie `git rm --cached -r .` and then `git add` and then comitting and pushing.

Does... anyone actually understand what I'm saying?  Is there really not a solution that can be spelled out?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you think "cloning the project" is, or what difference it would make. You seem to understand that, if you have made a commit that includes these `csv` files, then if you push a commit that has that commit as an ancestor, those `csv` files will indeed end up on GitHub. So it is hard to know what the question is.

One way to prevent that is to rewrite history, as with `git filter-repo`. You seem to know about that too, so again, it is hard to see what question you have. You would use `filter-repo` to remove the undesirable files from the history, also remove them from the most recent commit, and then push.

One final alternative: if you don't care *at all* about *any* of your commit history, another option would just be to squash all your existing commits into a single commit and push it; since the `csv` files are not present in the most recent commit, they will not be present in the squashed single commit that comprises all the commits.

Comment: despite "knowing about" the things I mention, I certainly don't know how to properly use them.  I tried ```git filter-repo --force --invert-paths --path-match *.csv``` which I found at https://www.baeldung.com/git-remove-file-commit-history, but nothing changes.  there are still "mysterious" csv files (which I don't even see in my working directory anymore) that blow up the push.

Comment: How could csv files "blow up" a push?

Comment: I mean that they're over 100mb, so I'm told that they exceed a size limit for github upload.  I don't want any of them pushed, regardless of their size

Comment: @blaughli In your [previous quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76276753/7976758) there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276781/7976758) `git filter-repo --path-glob '*.csv' --invert-paths`

Comment: A csv file that's over 100MB is one heck of a csv file.